# Angular-CLI v6: --no-aot build option equivalent

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I recently upgraded from Angular v5.2.4 partnered with Angular-CLI v1.7.4 to Angular v6.0.3 partnered with Angular-CLI v6.0.8.

My project requires a JIT compiler due to the use of dynamic components. As a result my build script use to be: `ng build --prod --no-aot`.

I need to continue to use the `--prod` flag to retain the benefits of the tree shaking, code minification, and dead code elimination. However, by default `--prod` enables AOT. The `--no-aot` option used to be the solution to disable AOT, yet still gain the benefits of the `--prod` build.

I've tried the following options and as you can see no builds have succeeded (except a standard `--prod` build). I am not getting any info back from the CLI either which is not very helpful:

[image]

I've read over the [Official Angular Deployment Docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) as well as the [Official Angular-CLI build Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) and have not found any information to help solve this issue.

**Does anyone know what the replacement for `--no-aot` option is OR the new way to do a `--prod` build while disabling AOT?**

Comment: `--aot=false --build-optimizer=false` should do it

Comment: Indeed `--aot false` was already the way to do it, `--no-aot` isn't documented for the old version either: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/1-x-build.

Comment: Not tested, but editing your angular.json file, and repacing `aot=true` by `aot=false` under projects/your-project/achitect/build/configurations/production should do it. And you would just have to use ng build --prod.

Comment: The combination of  `--aot=false --build-optimizer=false` did work. However, I like the idea of disabling AOT in the `angular.json` and removing the additional option. I will test that right now too.

Comment: Your suggestion worked too, @JBNizet (well partially)! In `angular.json` I change `aot=false` and `"buildOptimizer": false`  just like @R.Richards mentioned in his comment. With that combination I can now successfully do `ng build --prod` and get the same result as `ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false`

Comment: Thank you to all of you for your help in this matter! If any of you want to provide an answer I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To do this from the command line, use the following options along with the `--prod` option.

```
--aot=false --build-optimizer=false
```

The complete command:

```
ng b --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false
```

If you would rather avoid doing this on the command line each time, you can change the production build options in the *angular.json*.

At the following path in the file

```
projects/your-project/achitect/build/configurations/production
```

Change the `aot` and `buildOptimizer` options to `false`. Then, you can simply run `ng b --prod` from the command line, and you will get a production build that doesn't include the `aot` and `build-optimizer` options.

The `--prod` build option is deprecated. Below in the updated command.

```
ng b -c production --aot=false --build-optimizer=false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false
```

Answer (score 0):

In .npmrc file

```
legacy-peer-deps = true
```

Command Prompt

```
npm install
```

Or

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npm install
```